# Remote desktop hyper-v right click issue

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, hyper-v

I have a remote virtual server running on hyper-v. There right click is not working. Initially it started working fine, but after a while i'm facing the following issues * if i click the right mouse button it is not responding. * I lost the menu on top of all window. I checked for any overload issue, but none. Any one facing this same issue?

The issue get's fixed if the server restart is performed (only for a shorter time span), and i can't restart the server all the time this issue shows up.

Comment: Ensure you have got the latest version of Integration Services installed. (Click on Connect from Hyper-V manager and then use the Action menu to 'insert' the setup disk)

Comment: @Rikalous thank you for the info. 'll try it. Is there any possibilities that this might be caused by any virus injunctions?

Comment: Possible but unlikely. What is the guest OS? Is this an Remote Desktop connection or are you connecting from the Hyper-V management console?

Comment: OS is Windows server 2003. I'm connecting through Hyper-V mgmt console, but hyper-V is installed in a remote server. For now we have found a temporary fix. We performed the network connection repair yesterday and so far i can perform all the task without any issues. If u happen to know any permanent fix please share with us.